# Comparison function that compares two text files in Unix

Tags: bash, unix, cmp

I was wondering if anyone could tell me if there is a function available in unix, bash that compares all of the lines of the files. If they are different it should output true/false, or -1,0,1. I know these cmp functions exist in other languages. I have been looking around the man pages but have been unsuccessful. If it is not available, could someone help me come up with an alternative solution?

Thanks

Comment: `diff -u file1 file2` Note: diff's output can (and will) be used by the `patch` program to "edit" file1 into file2 (or vice versa)

Answer (score 38):

There are several ways to do this:

- `cmp -s file1 file2`: Look at the value of `$?`. Zero if both files match or non-zero otherwise.
- `diff file1 file2 > /dev/null`: Some forms of the `diff` command can take a parameter that tells it not to output anything. However, most don't. After all, you use `diff` to see the differences between two files. Again, the exit code (you can check the value of `$?` will be 0 if the files match and non-zero otherwise.

You can use these command in a shell if statement:

```
if cmp -s file1 file2
then
   echo "The files match"
else
   echo "The files are different"
fi
```

The `diff` command is made specifically for text files. The `cmp` command should work with all binary files too.

Comment: What if you want to make the if shorter, and only execute the `if` if files are different?  Can I just use `!`? I'm not clear I literally mean to reverse your logic, the first `then` would be "files doesn't match" and else "files match"

Answer (score 7):

There is a simple `cmp file file` command that does just that. It returns 0 if they are equal and 1 if they are different, so it's trivial to use in `if`s:

```
if cmp file1 file1; then
    ...
fi
```

Hope this helps =)

Comment: just beat me to it.  :-)  Adding a `-s` option will ensure that it is silent for differing files and only provides the return code so you don't get additional output

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash

file1=old.txt
file2=new.txt

echo " TEST 1 : "
echo

if [ $( cmp -s ${file1} ${file2}) ]
then
   echo "The files match :  ${file1} - ${file2}"
else
   echo "The files are different :  ${file1} - ${file2}"
fi

echo
echo " TEST 2 : "
echo
bool=$(cmp -s "$file1" "$file2" )
if cmp -s "$file1" "$file2"
then
   echo "The files match"
else
   echo "The files are different"
fi

echo
echo " TEST 3 : md5 / md5sum - compute and check MD5 message digest"
echo

md1=$(md5 ${file1});
md2=$(md5 ${file2});

mdd1=$(echo $md1 | awk '{print $4}' ) 
mdd2=$(echo $md2 | awk '{print $4}' ) 

# or md5sum depends on your linux flavour :D
#md1=$(md5sum ${file1});
#md2=$(md5sum ${file2});

#mdd1=$(echo $md1 | awk '{print $1}' ) 
#mdd2=$(echo $md2 | awk '{print $1}' ) 

echo $md1
echo $mdd1
echo $md2
echo $mdd2
echo

#if [ $mdd1 = $mdd2 ]; 
if [ $mdd1 -eq $mdd2 ]; 
then
   echo "The files match :  ${file1} - ${file2}"
else
   echo "The files are different :  ${file1} - ${file2}"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do an [md5](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_md5sum.htm) on the two files, then compare the results in `bash`.

No Unix box here to test, but this should be right.

```
#!/bin/bash

md1=$(md5 file1);
md2=$(md5 file2);

if [ $md1 -eq $ $md2 ]; then
  echo The same
else
  echo Different
fi
```

Comment: This will not work because it is always different, because the name of the file is also printed.
See in one of the previous answers : TEST 3 :
`md1=$(md5 ${file1});
md2=$(md5 ${file2});

mdd1=$(echo $md1 | awk '{print $4}' ) 
mdd2=$(echo $md2 | awk '{print $4}' ) 

if [ $mdd1 -eq $mdd2 ]; `

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12736013/comparison-function-that-compares-two-text-files-in-unix/36638506#36638506 ]

Answer (score 0):

echo "read first file"
read f1
echo "read second file"
read f2

diff -s f1 f2 # prints if both files are identical